# XML validation of required fields and any number of unknown optional fields

Tags: xslt, saxon, xsd-validation

I am not experienced with Saxon but have been tasked to determine a solution for the following problem:

Currently my client is using Saxonica to validate incoming XML documents. They are having an issue with optional fields. Currently they have a lot of optional fields in their validation that change quite a bit. Updating their schema to allow these optional fields is very difficult since they need to go through other departments to update production files.

Does Saxonica have the functionality to validate an XML document against a certain number of required fields and any number of optional fields. That is to say, allow the validation to go through if the required fields are present and the remaining optional fields have not been defined in the schema. They cannot update their schema fast enough with the never ending optional fields being added and modified. So if they could just check the required fields and let everything after that through.

If this is possible, can someone point me in the right direction of how this could be implemented. I am going through the documentation but haven't really found what I am looking for.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: There is `xsd:any` https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Wildcards but you will need to be more specific to allow us to tell whether it helps.

Comment: @MartinHonnen thanks for the help. What I am trying to do is validate an XML document that has option sections that I won't have in my validation schema. I have the required fields in my validation schema, but the optional fields are changing at such a fast rate that I would like my validation to accept XML documents that have the required fields  plus any random optional fields

Comment: Well, try to use `xsd:any` and/or `xsd:anyAttribute` with the specifiers you need. Not sure what you consider a field, whether that is an element or an attribute.

Comment: @Matt_ello: You seemed to have completely ignored Martin's suggestion to investigate `xsd:any` and instead chose to just restate your needs.

Comment: @kjhughes I did look into what Martin was saying but he asked me to be more specific and that is what I tried to do.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am looking into what you sent, It seems to be working but need to wait for confirmation. I appreciate your help

Comment: When i asked you to be more specific I was thinking about showing us a snippet of an element or type definition in a schema together with some input snippets you want to validate against that definition, showing us the number and position of optional fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you've got an instance and a schema, and the instance doesn't conform to the schema, and you don't want to change the schema for political/process reasons. Most people would say that you should fix the political obstacles. But if you absolutely need to work around them, then the other option is to change the instance so it conforms to the schema. People tend to forget that it's possible to do a transformation followed by a validation. Use XSLT to get rid of the "optional fields" and then use schema validation to validate what remains.